# Firebase security rules for mobile apps

Tags: flutter, firebase, security, mobile-application, rules

I am bit confused about firebase security rules. Do we need to write firebase security rules only for websites or should we write it for mobile apps also. I am trying to build a mobile app. Do I need to use firebase security rules (firebase is my backend) for my mobile app or is firebase security rules only for websites and is not required to write it for my mobile app. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: It is for both.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Answer (score 2):

Security rules save your data from being Update/Read/Write/Delete by unauthorized user, they are not web or app specific they are globally applied on you database (Firestore or Real Time Database) and Firebase Storage).

for more please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/

Comment: So, if I donot write security rules for my mobile app. Is my mobile app unsafe

Comment: If your app is an e-commerce App , you would like  any user access the card details of another user.

Comment: so without like writing separate code for security, using Security Rules you can define the security in a declarative and simplest way.